# Error When Install Ubuntu on Virtual Box

Tags: windows, virtualbox, windows-xp

I`m wanting to install Ubuntu 13.10 on virtual machine(VirtualBox)
but I got an error when I want to boot Ubuntu
.
.

```
This Kernel reguires the following features not pasent on the CPU: 
pea
Unable to boot - olease use a kernel appropriate for your CPU
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be one of these problems

1. Reboot your physical machine and go in your BIOS at start.

   Enable Intel VT (Virtualization Technology) or AMD-V (AMD Virtualization)

   depending on your processor's type.
2. Run VirtualBox.exe, click Settings, select System in the left pane then go in

   Processor tab.

   Check Enable PAE/NX.
3. This message could mean that you are trying to run a 64 Bits operating system with a

   non 64-Bits compatible processor.

   Recreate your Live USB using a standard 32 Bits ISO instead of a 64 Bits one.

hope it helps

Comment: I Have a 32 bits version of ubuntu ! (Ubuntu.v13.10.desktop.x86.iso)

Comment: ok.. try others options it may help

Comment: Which options ?

Comment: 1 and 2 options i mean..